# How to set field value based on the value of other fields in FormFlow in botframework?

Tags: c#, botframework, formflow

I am using FormFlow to build my bot using botframework (C#). And i have two optional fields. Based on the value of these two fields i want to set the value of third field **ReportRequest** as "application" if value in **ApplicationName** is present, or "project" if only value in **PojectName** is present, or "application,project" if value in both fields is present. I do not want to prompt user to ask ReportRequest field. I want to set it internally

```
[Optional]
[Prompt("What is the application name? {||}")]
public string ApplicationName { get; set; }

[Optional]
[Prompt("What is the project name? {||}")]
public string PojectName { get; set; }

public string ReportRequest = string.Empty;
```

I tried to do following but it doesn't seem to work

```
public static IForm<StandardInfoForm> BuildForm()
        {
            var parser = new Parser();
            return new FormBuilder<StandardInfoForm>()
                .Message("Welcome to reporting information!!")
                .Field(nameof(ApplicationName))
                .Field(nameof(ProjectName))
                .Confirm(async (state) =>
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(state.ApplicationName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(state.PojectName))
                    {
                        state.ReportRequest = "application,project";
                    }
                    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(state.ApplicationName))
                    {
                        state.ReportRequest = "application";
                    }
                    else (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(state.PojectName))
                    {
                        state.ReportRequest = "project";
                    }
                    return new PromptAttribute("Would you like to confirm.Yes or No");
                })
#pragma warning restore CS1998 // Async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously
                .Build();

        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change flow of messages in Microsoft Bot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40543581/change-flow-of-messages-in-microsoft-bot-framework)

Comment: Or duplicate of [MS Bot Framework Conversation with Decisions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40043804/ms-bot-framework-conversation-with-decisions)

Comment: @EzequielJadib Actually, i don't want to prompt user for setting the values of ReportRequest. And also both first and second field are optional and i am filling them by EntityRecommendation class from LUIS

Comment: Why do you want to do it in the confirm? Why you can't do it just outside of the form, once it's completed?

Comment: @EzequielJadib Please correct me if i am being too naive. The only reason i am doing it inside the form is because i can't access the Fields outside  without state

Comment: I'm writing the answer hold on.

Comment: @EzequielJadib Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the `ReportRequest` field is not being used within the form, I believe that you should move the logic either out of the Form (meaning, basically to the `ResumeAfter<T>` method that you specified at the time of calling the `FormDialog`) or to the `OnCompletion` delegate.

#### Out of the form option

You probably are doing something like the following to call your FormDialog:

```
  var form = new FormDialog<StandardInfoForm>(new StandardInfoForm(), StandardInfoForm.BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart);
  context.Call(form, this.AfterForm);
```

The `ResumeAfter<T>` method (in this example: `AfterForm`) will receive the state of the form as the `Awaitable` parameter:

```
private async Task AfterForm(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<StandardInfoForm> result)
{
    var state = await result;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(state.ApplicationName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(state.PojectName))
    {
        state.ReportRequest = "application,project";
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(state.ApplicationName))
    {
        state.ReportRequest = "application";
    }
    else (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(state.PojectName))
    {
        state.ReportRequest = "project";
    }
}
```

#### On completion option

When defining your form you could take advantage of the `OnCompletion` delegate

```
public static IForm<StandardInfoForm> BuildForm()
{
    var parser = new Parser();
    return new FormBuilder<StandardInfoForm>()
        .Message("Welcome to reporting information!!")
        .Field(nameof(ApplicationName))
        .Field(nameof(ProjectName))
        .Confirm("Would you like to confirm.Yes or No")
        .OnCompletion(async (context, state) =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(state.ApplicationName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(state.PojectName))
            {
                state.ReportRequest = "application,project";
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(state.ApplicationName))
            {
                state.ReportRequest = "application";
            }
            else (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(state.PojectName))
            {
                state.ReportRequest = "project";
            }
            return new PromptAttribute("Would you like to confirm.Yes or No");
        })
        .Build();
}
```